# how to pass a parameter to meteor helper that returns an object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass a parameter to a meteor helper and insert in HTML a property of the object returned, and not merely a final value returned.   I have something like this:

HTML:

```
<Template name ="conversationList">
  {{#each conversation}}
    {{getName.userName convStarterId}}  convStarterId its a property of conversation object     
  {{/each}}
</Template>
```

Helper:

```
Template.conversationList.helpers({
  getName: function(Id){
    return Members.findOne({userId:Id})  // the Object returned have a property userName},
  conversation: function() {  //return info from another collection
  }
});
```

It seems the 3rd line of my html is not working...

Comment: Please [edit] to make sure your code isn't bugged or poorly indented (there's multiple missing closing brackets). The syntax of your helper call is not valid. Why not simply return the `userName` value of the object returned by `findOne`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make `userName`  available in your template:

```
<template name="conversationList">
  {{#each conversation}}
    {{getName convStarterId}}     
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.conversationList.helpers({
  getName: function(Id){
    return Members.findOne({userId:Id}).userName;
  },
  conversation: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.   Although, there are 3 properties I want to read from the object and insert them in different parts of my HTML.   There is a way of reading the properties in HTML without doing 3 different 'findOne' queries?

Comment: Store a reference to the fetched member object and return an object literals with the properties you want:

`var member = Members.findOne({userId:Id}).fetch();
 return {
   userName: member.userName,
   myProp: member.myProp,
   ...
 }`

Comment: Excelent!  Thank you @Francesco